# Manga: reincarnated in another world (possibly as duke's child). MC is great at magic, makes useful tools (chess, soap, etc) & delicious food

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I am not 100% sure, but I believe this was a manga & not a manhwa. I read it a while back & wanted to wait a while to read a bunch of chapters at once, but it doesn't appear in my list anymore. In the last chapter I remember reading, there was a village festival going on and a chess championship was held. The main character (MC) of course won that. The MC also recently met an adventurer(?) who was a fan of the MC's father (I think the father became the duke after defeating a dragon or a similar, terrible creature).

Comment: What is the main character's gender? And do you remember about when you read this, or about how far into the story this festival is?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this in the request. MC is male. The festival is pretty earlier one, my guess would be around chapter 30?

Comment: @Moody Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You appear to have lost the account you posted the question with.  Please [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can edit these details into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be thinking of ***[I Want to Live a Slow Life in the Countryside After Reincarnation](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/p78i3qo/tensei-shite-inaka-de-slowlife-wo-okuritai)***.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tensei-shite-inaka-de-slow-life-wo-okuritai):

> Inaka Yuuji, was ran over by a truck because his awareness was dulled from overworking. “Ahー, with this I don’t have to work so much anymore. I want to spend my next life leisurely……” was the wish Yuuji blurted out, He met God and it was decided he will be reincarnated in the countryside of the otherworld. He became Alfred Slowlet, 2nd son of a countryside noble, will he be able to enjoy and leisurely spend his slow life in the countryside?

A man is reincarnated in another world as Alfred Slowlette, the second son of a feudal lord. Having felt overworked in his previous life, he decides he wants to live a slow-paced life in the countryside.

Even as a small boy, he can already use magic for things like teleportation, and utilises his knowledge of cooking to prepare Earth dishes such as spaghetti for his new family.

He also creates a reversi board and pieces, and the game becomes popular enough in this world that a tournament is held without his knowledge, and won by a girl. The girl then challenges him to a match, which he wins.

He later meets an adventurer who speaks highly of his father, referring to him as Nord the Dragonslayer, the man who saved the royal capital from a dragon.

[image]

[image]